# php/codeigniter login not working

Tags: php, codeigniter

I followed [this](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/easy-authentication-with-codeigniter/) awesome tutorial to create a very simple (one level) login system. But i always redirected back to my login form (`login() method in controller`) every time i tried to login.

This is my controller's code :

```
public function login() {
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('txt_email', 'Email', 'required|valid_email');    

        if($this->form_validation->run() !== FALSE)
        {
            $log_in = $this->backend_m->log_in($this->input->post('txt_email'), $this->input->post('txt_password'));
            if($log_in !== FALSE)
            {
                $_SESSION['username'] = $this->input->post('txt_email');
                redirect('backend/index');
            }
            //redirect('backend/index');
        }

        $this->load->view('backend/login_v');
    }
```

This is the `backend/index` first code (the one i redirect after login, **i think the error is here** because i always redirected back to `backend/login`) :

```
public function index() {
    //check authorization
    if(!isset($_SESSION['username']))
        redirect('backend/login');
```

This is my model :

```
public function log_in($email, $password) {
        $result = $this->db->where('email', $email)->where('password', sha1($password))->get('mspengurus');     

        if($result->num_rows() > 0 )
            return $result->row();

        return FALSE;
    }
```

This is my view :

```
<body>
    <div id="login">
        <h1>Login - GABDB</h1>
        <?php echo form_open('backend'); ?>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <?php echo form_label('Email :', 'lbl_email'); ?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <?php echo sha1('admin'); ?>
                        <?php echo form_input('txt_email', set_value('txt_email'), 'id="txt_email"'); ?>
                        <?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <?php echo form_label('Password :', 'lbl_password'); ?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <?php echo form_password('txt_password', '', 'id="txt_password"'); ?>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <?php echo form_submit('btn_submit', 'Log In', 'id = "btn_submit"'); ?>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        <?php echo form_close(); ?>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: For some reasons, your session is not set. try putting echo for $this->input->post('txt_email') and $_SESSION['username'] inside the if condition n check it.

Answer (score 0):

use this method to set session in your login() function

```
$this->load->library('session'); 
$seesion_data = array(
                   'username'  => $this->input->post('txt_email'),

                   'logged_in' => TRUE
               );

 $this->session->set_userdata($seesion_data);
```

use this in index() function

```
$this->load->library('session');
$username = $this->session->userdata('username');
if(empty($username)){
 redirect('backend/login');
}
```